# Run expect script which spawn screen over SSH - Set terminal type

Tags: ssh, expect

I have an Expect script which spawn a screen session to read an embedded board console and give respond automatically.
I have no issue while executing the Expect script locally in the host.

But when I wish to execute the script from another machine to that host via ssh, for example `ssh ubuntu@172.30.248.123 './flash-the-board.sh'`, I will get the prompt

```
Please set a terminal type
```

I have try to set `TERM=vt100` in the SSH command before running the bash script, end up i got the error

```
expect: read eof
screen is terminating
```

Anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks

Comment: Try `ssh -t ubuntu@172.30.248.123 './flash-the-board.sh'`, please. It is a wild guess but easy to check.

Comment: i have no control on the ssh part as it is a system that send command to machine. Wish to know any environment configuration i can do in that machine itself

Comment: who reported *"Please set a terminal type"*?

Comment: I just found out that the "Please set a terminal type" was prompted when i spawn `screen`. I have fixed it with added `set ::env(TERM) vt100` at the beginning of my Expect script instead of export it before running script. However, i am not sure what is the difference, hopefully someone can explain

Comment: why do you need to spawn `screen`? `expect` can talk to serial ports directly e.g. https://github.com/thrig/arduino/blob/master/serial/bytesreader.tcl